# Elif and range functions for progressive taxation calculation in percentage

Tags: python, if-statement, range, percentage

I am creating a program where user puts yearly income as an input and the income taxation rate would scale according to percentage thresholds (see picture at the end of this post for income range vs. percentage thresholds). For example from 100,000 euro income 50% would be paid from income exceeding 60001 (as according in the table below). 40% betweeen 45000-60000, 20% between 15000-30000 and 10% between 0-10000. Equation should go something like 0.5* 40 000 + 0.4 * 150 00 + 0.3 * 15 000 + 0.2 * 15 000 + 0.1 * 10000 = 35 000.

Outputs should be something like:
Give your yearly income: 100000 You pay taxes 35000.0 euro. Your taxation percent is: 35.0 %.
Give your yearly income: 54000 You pay taxes 12600.0 euroa. Your taxation percent is: 23.333333333333332 %.

This is what I've tried:

```
yearly = int(input("Tell your yearly income:"))
one = 0.1
two = 0.2
three = 0.3
four = 0.4
five = 0.5 
if yearly in range(1,15000):
    print("You pay taxes in total:",yearly*one)
if yearly in range(15001,30000):
    print("You pay taxes in total:",yearly*two)
if yearly in range(30001,45000):
    print("You pay taxes in total:",yearly*three)
if yearly in range(45001,60000):
    print("You pay taxes in total:",yearly*four)
if yearly > 60000:
    print("You pay taxes in total:",yearly*five)
```

The taxation percent doesn't scale like I'd like it to. I assumption is that this should get done by elif and range functions. Maybe min and max values of percentages would help, but I don't know how to turn outputs into percentages. Please note that I might have some comprehension problems here, math is not my strongest gamem but I did my absolute best to describe the problem...

Here is a table of income count vs. taxation percentage used. 
[Income vs. taxation percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHDbC.png)

Comment: Are you asking how to do the tax calculation correctly or how to print a number like 0.35 as "35%"?

Comment: As described in desired outputs, I want both like; "Your taxation percent is X" and "You pay xxxxx taxes"

Answer (score -1):

**Optimized way :**

Here is a more-optimized way to do it (see at bottom for a non-optimized way with enumeration). I store the percents and thresholds in lists, and `taxes` is incremented during a loop :

```
yearly = int(input("Tell your yearly income:"))

percents = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
thresholds = [0, 15000, 30000, 45000, 60000]

taxes = 0
for i in range(len(percents)):
    if i == len(thresholds) - 1 or yearly < thresholds[i+1]:
        taxes += (yearly - thresholds[i]) * percents[i]
        break
    else:
        taxes += (thresholds[i+1] - thresholds[i]) * percents[i]

print("You pay {} taxes".format(taxes))
print("Your taxation percent is: {}%".format(taxes/yearly*100))
```

Examples of outputs :

```
# Test 1
Tell your yearly income:100000
You pay 35000.0 taxes
Your taxation percent is: 35.0%

# Test 2
Tell your yearly income:54000
You pay 12600.0 taxes
Your taxation percent is: 23.333333333333332%
```

**Non-optimized way :**

Here the key is to have a variable `temp` (initialized with `temp = yearly` that decreases when you apply the taxes :

```
yearly = int(input("Tell your yearly income:"))

one = 0.1
two = 0.2
three = 0.3
four = 0.4
five = 0.5

diff = 15000

temp = yearly
taxes = 0
if yearly in range(1,15000):
    taxes += temp * one
else:
    taxes += diff * one
    temp -= diff
if yearly in range(15001,30000):
    taxes += temp * two
else:
    taxes += diff * two
    temp -= diff
if yearly in range(30001,45000):
    taxes += temp * three
else:
    taxes += diff * three
    temp -= diff
if yearly in range(45001,60000):
    taxes += temp * four
else:
    taxes += diff * four
    temp -= diff
if yearly > 60000:
    taxes += temp * five

print("You pay {} taxes".format(taxes))
print("Your taxation percent is: {}%".format(taxes/yearly*100))
```