# progressive tax calculation over several years with only numpy arrays (no dictionary)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, numba

I build from the following code

```
yearly = int(input("Tell your yearly income:"))

percents = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
thresholds = [0, 15000, 30000, 45000, 60000]

taxes = 0
for i in range(len(percents)):
    if i == len(thresholds) - 1 or yearly < thresholds[i+1]:
        taxes += (yearly - thresholds[i]) * percents[i]
        break
    else:
        taxes += (thresholds[i+1] - thresholds[i]) * percents[i]

print("You pay {} taxes".format(taxes))
print("Your taxation percent is: {}%".format(taxes/yearly*100))
```

which was posted as a solution to the question in [Elif and range functions for progressive taxation calculation in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279199/elif-and-range-functions-for-progressive-taxation-calculation-in-percentage).

Now say I have one array `percents` and one array `thresholds` which differ for several years. For example, for years between 1973 and 1979, say I have like in the example

```
percents_1 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
thresholds_1 = [0, 15000, 30000, 45000, 60000]
```

while for years between 1980 and 1982 I have

```
percents_2 = [0.1, 0.2]
thresholds_2 = [0, 45000]
```

which means the arrays can differ in dimension for different years. The idea is to build a function like in the example but which takes as an input the year as well, recognizes which `percents` and  `thresholds` are the correct ones for that year and then calculates taxes as above. I have implemented such a function using dictionaries and it was pretty simple. Now I want to "translate" it using only arrays and matrices to remain in the numpy world and being able to apply Numba to such function. I was thinking to use a multi-dimensional array where the first dimension identifies the year, the second dimension contains the `percents` values and the third contains the `thresholds` values. The problem is that `percents` and  `thresholds` have different dimensions for different years. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: May I ask why no dictionaries?

Comment: As far as I understood, Numba has very limited implementation for dictionaries, i.e. One needs to necessarily pass them as empty objects and fill them within the function to (say) decorate with @jit. I guess this would slow down my function,? But I am happy to hear that there are other solutions involving dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

I have extended your code with the requirements

```py
yearly = int(input("Tell your yearly income:"))
## Change 1
year = input('Which year would you like to calculate the tax for?')

# Change 2
tax_vals = [
  ['1973-1979', [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [0, 15000, 30000, 45000, 60000]],
  ['1980-1982', [0.1, 0.2], [0, 45000]]
]


## Change 3
percents = []
thresholds = []
for r, p, t  in tax_vals:
  start, end = r.split('-')
  if int(start)<=year<=int(end): 
    percents = p
    thresholds = t
    break

taxes = 0
for i in range(len(percents)):
    if i == len(thresholds) - 1 or yearly < thresholds[i+1]:
        taxes += (yearly - thresholds[i]) * percents[i]
        break
    else:
        taxes += (thresholds[i+1] - thresholds[i]) * percents[i]

print("You pay {} taxes".format(taxes))
print("Your taxation percent is: {}%".format(taxes/yearly*100))
```

Comment: It looks nice, but I am afraid if I try to put everything into a function and decorate it with @jit(nopython=True) it will throw me the usual error due to unrecognized dictionary type, won't it?

Comment: Definetly, I'll update the solution accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the years to be indices into a list of arrays.
Take differences for the tax rates from band to band.
Multiply these difference rates by the maximum of income - thresholds and zero.
Sum this result.

There are many ways to organise the data.  One alternative is to always have (e.g.) ten rates/thresholds and leave the unused ones at zero or the last real threshold.  This means all the data can go into a numpy array.  I've not done this below.

```
import numpy as np

percents = []
thresholds = []

percents.append( np.array( [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5] ))
thresholds.append( np.array([0, 15000, 30000, 45000, 60000]) )

percents.append( np.array([0.1, 0.2]) )
thresholds.append( np.array([0, 45000]))

BASE_YEAR = 1973

#          73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 ; This could be scripted.
year_ix = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ]

def year_to_ix( year ):
    return year_ix[ year -  BASE_YEAR ]

def difference( arr ):
    result = arr.copy()
    result[1:] = arr[1:] - arr[:-1]
    return result

delta_rate = [ difference( arr ) for arr in percents ]
# This is the change in tax rate from band to band 

def tax_calc( income, year ):
    # Fetch the data needed for the calculation 
    y_ix = year_to_ix( year )
    d_rate = delta_rate[ y_ix ]
    threshold = thresholds[ y_ix ] 

    # Do the calculation 
    taxable = np.maximum( income - threshold, 0 ) # maximum(x,0) sets any negative x to zero
    return ( taxable * d_rate).sum()
```